# MYSQL - count number of rows in each table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how many rows are in each table in my database. I've come so far as to having

```
select count(*) _tablename_;
```

However i would need to do that on each and every table - and there are a lot. What would me the best way to get a print-out with the table name and it's row count?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your db>';
```

I also hope you realise there's an error in your query: it's missing a `FROM`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've got the part that it's better to get the list from metadata!

Comment: Oops... I tried this query but it gives unstable results (each time different values)!

Comment: Yes, the inaccuracy of InnoDB row counts is a by-product of that engine as mentioned here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: Specifically: "InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the same time. [...] If an approximate row count is sufficient, SHOW TABLE STATUS can be used."

Comment: you can also improve this a bit by using `format(table_rows)` and getting some `,`'s in there so you can read the row count easier.

Comment: To get correct results, run ``` ANALYZE TABLE table_name```. see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/297831/236769

Answer (score 4):

This following query will return number of rows in each table but it doesn't seem to return exact value all the time

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your db>';
```

**TABLE_ROWS**: The number of table rows in the partition. For partitioned InnoDB tables, the row count given in the TABLE_ROWS column is only an estimated value used in SQL optimization, and may not always be exact...
for more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.5/en/partitions-table.html

Comment: how it is different from the above answer?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SQL queries by others, one can also use Workbench GUI to get the row-counts of each table. To do this, Launch Workbench -> Connect to Db -> right click Db and select "Schema Inspector" (as in Screenshot below - I have highlighted the "Rows" column):

[image]

HTH.