# How to export to excel a database(mysql) report on my tables from workbench

Tags: mysql, database, report, mysql-workbench

I have a database on mysql with a bunch of tables, now I need a report on the amount of rows each table has.

mysql workbench provides a nice report with schema inspector but now I need to export it to excel but I can't seem to find the button or how to.

so anyone knows how to export it to excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting results of a Mysql query to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295228/exporting-results-of-a-mysql-query-to-excel)

Comment: no because it's not data from a table , it data about the data in the tables.
anyways i didn't know you could make a query on information table so it's allright

Comment: [MYSQL - count number of rows in each table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603272/mysql-count-number-of-rows-in-each-table) and save the results to excel as shown in my proposed duplicate?